# Do not display the banner after clicking on the button for 1 week?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

When I arrived on my site, I created a banner. I would like that when the user clicks once on it to make it disappear, that it does not appear any more during 1 week.
For the moment, when I click on it, it ends up reappearing when I refresh my page...
Thank you very much

Here my code : html code

```
        <div class="border-alert-site " role="alert">
          <span style="font-size: 15px;" class="text-white">Blabla</span>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria
label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
```

My jquery code

```
  $(".close").click(function () {
    Cookies.set('.border-alert-site', true, { expires: 7 });
    $('.border-alert-site').hide();
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HTML**

```
        <div class="border-alert-site" role="alert">
          <span style="font-size: 15px;" class="text-white">Blabla</span>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria
label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
        </div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function() {
  const cookie = Cookies.get('border-alert-site');
  if (cookie) {
     $('.border-alert-site').hide();
  }
  $(".close").click(function () {
    Cookies.set('border-alert-site', true, { expires: 7 });
    $('.border-alert-site').hide();
  });
});
```